# Changing part of a cmd command

Tags: menu, cmd

I have this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

and i want to be able to change what is written after /C in this line

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/C";
```

I also want it in form of a text box and drop down menu. Is that possible?
To explain: I want to be able to write in a text box  a command i want and then in dropdown menu i will choose few more word that will be included in the command.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your tags. Anything you want to add you add after `/c`.

Your question is about some unknown programming language and a forms package.

IN VBS

```
Cmd = Inputbox("Enter command?")
```

then

```
wshshell.run "cmd /c " & Cmd
```